# NHibernate recreates every associated item

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a very simple object models.

```
public class Contact
{
    public virtual int Id                { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name           { get; set; }
    public virtual Device Device         { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<string> Numbers { get; set; }

    public Contact()
    {
        Numbers = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>(3);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class Contact has an association with Numbers, which is a list of strings.

Here's the mapping:

```
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.Device, "DeviceId");
        Table("Contacts");
        HasMany(x => x.Numbers)
            .Table("ContactNumbers")
            .Element("Number")
            .KeyColumn("ContactId")
            .LazyLoad()
            .Cascade.All()
            .Not
            .Inverse();
```

Note that I can't and don't want the collection to be inverse=true, because it's just a collection of string. This means that Contact is responsible for updating Numbers entries. 
Now my problem is that, whenever I try to add a new number to an existing Contact, it deletes all associated numbers and recreates them individually. Isn't NHibernate smart enough to detect changes and update only changed items?

I think there should be a simple solution for my problem but don't know what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually [documented](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections) in NHibernate's documentation.

> Bags are the worst case. Since a bag permits duplicate element values
>   and has no index column, no primary key may be defined. NHibernate has
>   no way of distinguishing between duplicate rows. NHibernate resolves
>   this problem by completely removing (in a single DELETE) and
>   recreating the collection whenever it changes. This might be very
>   inefficient.

Try using an [`<idbag>`](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-idbag) mapping instead, and create a surrogate primary key for that table. Unfortunately, looks like `<idbag>` is [not yet supported](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-list-array-idbag.html) in [FluentNHibernate](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Mapping/ToManyBase.cs).

Also, take a look at other [collection mapping options](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/17/mapping-collections-in-nhibernate-part-1).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion and let's see what happens :)

Comment: Well, that's my luck :(. Any other alternatives? :(

Comment: I guess you could use hbm or mapping-by-code, just for that entity... or try with list mapping instead: http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list. FluentNHibernate supports it: `HasMany...AsList()`.

Comment: Thanks Miraslav, I think your last suggestion is closest to my needs, however it has some caveats when removing items from collection and that's what's keeping me from using it :(. mapping with hbm file is also out of question due to the policy. So I guess there is no other way left? :(

Comment: Well, you can always add support for `idbag` to FNH. It's open source after all :) How about `<set>` mapping then? You would need to modify property type to Iesi.Collection's `ISet` though, or try to use .NET 4.0's `ISet`: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/03/15/using-lt-set-gt-in-mappings-without-iesi-collections-net-4.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for that answer Miroslav, I had the same issue with my collections and after adding making it inverse the problem went away, but I still couldn't work out why it was trying to delete the child collection every time - this answers the question!

Comment: Aslo I knew your name was familiar, remember seeing you on Rocky's CSLA forums!

Comment: Yes, I also thought about ISet, but it can contain only unique values, and in my case, duplicates is possible. Damn, It's too complicated :D

Comment: @Charleh LOL... those were the good days :) I've been working on CSLAgen looong time ago.

Comment: @Davita Guess YYY's suggestion for a full blown entity is not that repulsive anymore ;)

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic wait, having a full blown entity as a collection of bag will fix my primary issue? :)

Comment: it should... since you'll have an id / primary key in that case.

Comment: @MiroslavPopovic I understand muuuch better now the magic involved behind the scenes. Thank you very much for pointing me to the right direction. I'll mark your answer as answer and upvote YYY :)

Comment: @Davita not a problem, glad I could help